# Syntax error in simple Python 3.2.2 program

Tags: python, syntax

This code is example code from a book on python. It is a simple program to enter integers and display the sum, total count, and average of the integers. However, when I try to run the code, I receive a syntax error at line 18, the colon. This code looks perfectly fine to me. Any ideas?

```
print("type integers, each followed by Enter; or just Enter to finish")

total = 0
count = 0

while True:
    line = input("integer: "
    if line:
        try:
            number = int(line)
        except ValueError as err:
            print(err)
            continue
    total += number
    count += 1
    else:
        break
if count:
    print("count=", count, "total =", total, "mean =", total / count)
```

When i try and run this, I get an error:

```
  File "./intproj.py", line 18
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am using IDLE as an IDE with python 3.2.2 on Ubuntu 11.10

---

updated code:

```
print("type integers, each followed by Enter; or just Enter to finish")

total = 0
count = 0

while True:
    line = input("integer: ")
    if line:
        try:
            number = int(line)
        except ValueError as err:
                print(err)
                continue
    total += number
    count += 1
    else:
        break
if count:
    print("count=", count, "total =", total, "mean =", total / count)
```

and now get the error:

```
  File "./intproj.py", line 18
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

Fixed code:

```
print("type integers, each followed by Enter; or just Enter to finish")

total = 0
count = 0

while True:
    line = input("integer: ")
    if line:
        try:
            number = int(line)
        except ValueError as err:
                print(err)
                continue
        total += number
        count += 1
    else:
        break
if count:
    print("count=", count, "total =", total, "mean =", total / count)
```

Thanks!

Comment: well, the previous line seems to missing a `)` `line = input("integer: "`

Comment: You've changed your question in response to our answers, which makes this question less useful. A good way to fix this would be to post the original, a horizontal line, and then your edits that happened in response to our answers.

Answer (score 6):

line 9 seems to missing a `)`

change:

```
line = input("integer: "
```

into

```
line = input("integer: ")
```

The `except` line need to be indented to match the `try`

and the lines:

```
total += number
count += 1
```

needs to be indented as well otherwise, the `if` and the `else` statements don't line up. I.e. code should be something like this:

```
print("type integers, each followed by Enter; or just Enter to finish")

total = 0
count = 0

while True:
    line = input("integer: ")
    if line:
        try:
            number = int(line)
        except ValueError as err:
            print(err)
            continue
        total += number
        count += 1
    else:
        break
if count:
    print("count=", count, "total =", total, "mean =", total / count)
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close your `input()` call on the previous line.

Answer (score 1):

You need a closing bracket:

```
line = input("integer: ")
```

Comment: @BillyBach, the indentation for `except` does not match the one for `try`

Comment: Your updated code has the "total += number" line and the "count += 1" lines un-indented relative to the if block. You should indent those. Also, please re-edit your question to include the original and your edit to the code so that our answers make sense.

Comment: updated the original code instead of posting repeat blocks of code with corrections

Comment: @Sancho alright i see what your saying, ill post the corrected blocks

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the closing parenthesis issue, your line that says `except ValueError as err:` is not indented enough (its indentation level should match that of the `try` statement). That should fix the line 18 `else` error you mentioned above.

Comment: by "it should match that of the try statement" do you mean: try: and then the statement on the same level of the try: or one in under the try: statement?

Comment: the `try` and `except` lines should have the same number of spaces in front of them. Fredrik answered it better than I, you should look at his answer

Answer (score 0):

The lines starting with `total +=` and `count +=` need to start with eight spaces instead of four.